# How do I model a many to many relationship in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to model a many to many relationship.
I've read some documentation, but I don't know how to model.
I'll give you an example of what I want to do.
I have two entities, Album and song.
They have a many to many relationship.

```
class Song(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

class Album(models.Model):
       nombre = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
       songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, blank=True)
```

The user in the frontend, provides me the data of an album that I must save.
It provides me the name of the album and the name of the songs.
How could I model it on the serializers?
Nothing runs.

Comment: This [serializer relations guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) should get you started.

Comment: I've read it, by I am still lost

Answer (score 0):

I think you can delete that `blank=True` i think it automatically can be blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Song(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

class Album(models.Model):
       nombre = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
       songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, related_name='songs', blank=True)
```

and you can make the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Django will create a table for many to many relationships. You can do this by yourself as well with customized fields. For example, you may like to save the order for songs in an album:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

class AlbumSong(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    song = models.ForeignKey('Song', null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False)
    removed = Bit1BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
```